# Erfi[z] expansion in Mathematica: is this a bug?

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

Looking at the expansion:

```
Series[Erfi[x], {x, Infinity, 1}]
```

I obtain

```
-I+E^x^2 (1/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] x)+O[1/x]^2)
```

(note the imaginary argument in front). This looks wrong as I don't think there should be an imaginary number out front; I had thought that this was due to some branch cut about the positive x axis, but this doesn't look like the case. Looking at the output of Mupad (in Matlab), I obtain the correct expansion listed in the response [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58899).

Is this a bug?

Comment: The basis of the expansion about infinity can be found here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html

Comment: The basis of expansion can be found here
[doublemath](https://doublemath.com/erfi-imaginary-error-function/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is subtle, and relies on the fact that Mathematica and Maple seem to define the erfi(z) function differently. Mathematica defines erfi(z) as

```
erfi(z) = -i erf(iz)
```

whereas [Maple defines it](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=erf) according to

[image: Maple]

So I think what is happening is that Mathematica expands -i erf(iz). The expansion for erf(iz) is

```
1 + exp(z^2)/(sqrt(Pi)*z) + ...
```

so multiply by -i to obtain the strange answer in the original post. However, if you look at the integral definition, you see that the answer should be real if z is real. I believe Maple and Mupad are expanding the integral, and thus obtaining the 'correct' expansion at z real and infinity.

Mathematica is using an expansion for the erf(iz) function at z = infinity, and so making an expansion about the imaginary axis. Because of the way complex functions work, this may not be exactly the same thing.